# Hibernate: Automatically creating/updating the db tables based on entity classes

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, groovy

I have the following entity class (in Groovy):

```
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType

@Entity
public class ServerNode {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  Long id

  String firstName
  String lastName

}
```

and my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Icarus"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        </properties>
        <class>net.interaxia.icarus.data.models.ServerNode</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and the script:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
import javax.persistence.Persistence
import net.interaxia.icarus.data.models.ServerNode

def factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit")
def manager = factory.createEntityManager()

manager.getTransaction().begin()

manager.persist new ServerNode(firstName: "Test", lastName: "Server")

manager.getTransaction().commit()
```

the database *Icarus* exists, but currently has no tables. I would like Hibernate to automatically create and/or update the tables based on the entity classes. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I don't know if leaving `hibernate` off the front makes a difference.

The [reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-misc-properties) suggests it should be `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`

A value of `create` will create your tables at sessionFactory creation, and leave them intact.

A value of `create-drop` will create your tables, and then drop them when you close the sessionFactory.

Perhaps you should set the [`javax.persistence.Table`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/Table.html) annotation explicitly?

Comment: It was the missing 'hibernate' at the beginning of the hbm2dll.auto. thanks!

Comment: I just removed that line and it won't drop the table. Hope this helps!

Comment: how can I make hibernate to create tables only if they didn't exists?

Comment: it was the missing `javax.peristence.Table` for me, thanks

Answer (score 86):

You might try changing this line in your persistence.xml from

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

to:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

This is supposed to maintain the schema to follow any changes you make to the Model each time you run the app.

Got this from [JavaRanch](https://coderanch.com/forums/search/search/-1?match_type=all&sort_by=time&q=hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto&groupByTopic=true)

Comment: Eclipse complains: Attribute "value" must be declared for element type "property". when adding this property in config file

Comment: I suppose things could've changed in the 14 years since I answered this, but 83 up-votes makes me think I got it right.

Comment: Totally. Was just hoping someone might comment with updated answer. Asking new question will probably just get flagged as duplicate to this one xD.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes depending on how the configuration is set, the long form and the short form of the property tag can also make the difference.

e.g. if you have it like:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

try changing it to:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case table was not created for the first time without last property listed below:

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
    <!-- without below table was not created -->
    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
</properties>
```

used Wildfly's in-memory H2 database

Answer (score 2):

There is one very important detail, than can possibly stop your hibernate from generating tables (assuming You already have set the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`). You will also need the `@Table` annotation!

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_entity")
    public class TestEntity {
}
```

It has already helped in my case at least 3 times - still cannot remember it ;)

PS. Read the hibernate docs - in most cases You will probably not want to set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `create-drop`, because it deletes Your tables after stopping the app.

Answer (score 1):

1. TO CREATING TABLE AUTOMATIC , NO CONNECTION WITH ANNOTATIONS
2. FOR THAT WE NEED TO CHANGE "hibernate.cfg.xml" as like.

```
 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Comment: This solution has already been proposed in other answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

In applicationContext.xml file:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <!-- This makes /META-INF/persistence.xml is no longer necessary -->
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.howtodoinjava.demo.model" />
      <!-- JpaVendorAdapter implementation for Hibernate EntityManager.
           Exposes Hibernate's persistence provider and EntityManager extension interface -->
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
      </property>
      <property name="jpaProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

In support to @thorinkor's answer I would extend my answer to use not only @Table (name = "table_name") annotation for entity, but also every child variable of entity class should be annotated with @Column(name = "col_name"). This results into seamless updation to the table on the go.

For those who are looking for a Java class based hibernate config, the rule applies in java based configurations also(NewHibernateUtil). Hope it helps someone else.