# Is there a way to create database tables alongside classes in Spring Roo?

Tags: spring-roo

I have set up entities and their relationships with Spring Roo. I am trying to run "perform tests" through Roo but see that corresponding tables for these entities are not created in the datbase that I selected as part of my database setup.

Is there a way to tell Spring Roo to generate database tables, columns too alongside entities and its fields?

Comment: It is very strange because default roo setup should create tables on application's run. Please check your log if there are some exceptions you missed.

Comment: @Constantiner: That may be true for in memory database like Hypersonic. Is it also true for MySQL?

Comment: For in memory database tables are created on every run and destroyed after run. If you'll use MySQL tables will be persisted between sessions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to create the database yourself, then Hibernate will create the tables for you.  I had the same problem and my db user was root so I just assumed that Hibernate would create the database - but it wasn't.  As soon as I created the schema, everything worked fine.

The tables seem to be created during sessionFactory creation according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306806/hibernate-automatically-creating-updating-the-db-tables-based-on-entity-classes).

Comment: Thanks that worked! I had to create the database and when I fired the perform tests it created the tables on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Have you done the "persistence setup .." step? If so, you should have a persistence.xml in src/main/resources/META-INF. Do you have a property named "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" there? What is its value?

Comment: Thanks. I will try that and post the result back here.

Comment: Thanks - it is true. +1 for giving me some direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example of filling in memory DB with test data [here](http://bsgdev.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/exploring-google-and-openid-login-with-spring-security-and-spring-roo/). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - I am not looking for in memory solution. I am rather looking for how to achieve it using MYSql?

Comment: Just follow the link above. Filling test data routine checks if data already presents in DB. So it can be used for MySQL too.

Comment: I don't think you get the question. I am not asking about filling data. I am asking about creating schema (tables and columns) when Roo creates entities. Is that possible?

Comment: They are created automatically. By default.

Comment: When? At the time entity is created or during first run? 'co I am not seeing them and when I do perform tests - it complains about not having them.

Comment: Complains? In what form? Any exception? Please post stacktrace.