# Running my application with Spring, Hibernate, Tomcat, and MySQL Community Server

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat

I was building my application using [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) 2.5, [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) 3, [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) 7 and MySQL Community Server 5.1. I run the application and all works fine. The problem arise when I try to use the latest version of MySQL Server (MySQL Community Server 5.5), it seems that Hibernate can not create the tables. The error message says:

> table project.product doesn't exists...

Here are the Apache logs:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context path [/Project] threw exception[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query]  with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'project.products' doesn't exist

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context path [/Project] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query] with root cause
java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.


23-jul-2011 4:12:27 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context path [/Project] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'project.products' doesn't exist
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3603)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3535)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1989)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2150)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2281)
   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
   at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
   at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
   at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
   at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
   at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:926)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:917)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:909)
   at com.pj.dao.ProductDAOImpl.listProduct(ProductDAOImpl.java:32)
   at com.pj.web.IndexController.index(IndexController.java:69)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:409)
   at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:132)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:310)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:297)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:394)
   at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
   at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
   at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
   at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
   at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
   at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
   at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
   at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
   at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
   at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
   at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
   at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
   at org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:109)
   at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
   at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
   at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
   at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
   at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
   at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
   at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
   at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
   at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
   at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
   at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
   at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
   at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
   at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
   at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
   at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
   at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
   at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:185)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:851)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:278)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I made another test. I tried installing Tomcat 6 instead of Tomcat 7, and when I tried to run my application, it comes up a 404 error (resource is not available). What's wrong with my application?

Here are the logs:

```
23-jul-2011 4:57:56 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: java.library.path: C:\java\jdk\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\java\jdk\bin;.
    23-jul-2011 4:57:56 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
    INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8000
    23-jul-2011 4:57:56 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 476 ms
    23-jul-2011 4:57:56 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    23-jul-2011 4:57:56 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
    23-jul-2011 4:57:56 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
    INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
    23-jul-2011 4:57:56 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
    INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
    23-jul-2011 4:57:57 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
    INFO: Deploying web application archive Project.war
    23-jul-2011 4:57:57 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
    INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
    23-jul-2011 4:57:57 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@f8395f: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Sat Jul 23 04:57:57 CEST 2011]; root of context hierarchy
    23-jul-2011 4:57:58 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
    23-jul-2011 4:58:00 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-applicationContext.xml]
    23-jul-2011 4:58:00 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
    INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@f8395f]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@fd1810
    23-jul-2011 4:58:01 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
    INFO: Bean '(inner bean)' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    23-jul-2011 4:58:01 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
    INFO: Bean '_delegatingMethodDefinitionSource' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    23-jul-2011 4:58:01 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
    INFO: Bean '_methodDefinitionSourceAdvisor' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    23-jul-2011 4:58:02 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
    INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@fd1810: defining beans [viewResolver,myDataSource,mySessionFactory,myProductDAO,myUserDAO,myorderDAO,indexController,urlMapping,usuarioValidator,messageSource,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,_delegatingMethodDefinitionSource,_accessManager,_methodSecurityInterceptor,_methodSecurityInterceptorPostProcessor,_methodDefinitionSourceAdvisor,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,_authenticationManager,_filterChainProxy,_httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,_filterChainProxyPostProcessor,_filterChainList,_securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,_portMapper,_exceptionTranslationFilter,_filterSecurityInterceptor,_sessionFixationProtectionFilter,_anonymousAuthenticationProvider,_anonymousProcessingFilter,_rememberMeServices,_rememberMeAuthenticationProvider,_rememberMeFilter,_rememberMeServicesInjectionBeanPostProcessor,_logoutFilter,_basicAuthenticationEntryPoint,_basicAuthenticationFilter,_formLoginFilter,_formLoginEntryPoint,_entryPointInjectionBeanPostProcessor,_userServiceInjectionPostProcessor,org.springframework.security.providers.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0,org.springframework.security.config.AuthenticationProviderBeanDefinitionParser$AuthenticationProviderCacheResolver#0]; root of factory hierarchy
    23-jul-2011 4:58:05 org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean buildSessionFactory
    INFO: Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor afterPropertiesSet
    INFO: Validated configuration attributes
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.EntryPointInjectionBeanPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: Selecting AuthenticationEntryPoint for use in ExceptionTranslationFilter
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.EntryPointInjectionBeanPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: Using main configured AuthenticationEntryPoint.
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.EntryPointInjectionBeanPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: Using bean 'org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint@107b56e' as the entry point.
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor afterPropertiesSet
    INFO: Validated configuration attributes
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcUserDetailsManager initDao
    INFO: No authentication manager set. Reauthentication of users when changing passwords will not be performed.
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.RememberMeServicesInjectionBeanPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: Setting RememberMeServices on bean _basicAuthenticationFilter
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.FilterChainProxyPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: Checking sorted filter chain: [org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter[ order=200; ], org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter[ order=300; ], org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter[ order=700; ], org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter[ order=1000; ], org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter[ order=1100; ], org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter[ order=1200; ], org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter[ order=1300; ], org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter[ order=1400; ], org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter[ order=1600; ], org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor@aa559d]
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.FilterChainProxyPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: Filter chain...
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.FilterChainProxyPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: [0] - org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter[ order=200; ]
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.FilterChainProxyPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: [1] - org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter[ order=300; ]
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.FilterChainProxyPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: [2] - org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter[ order=700; ]
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.FilterChainProxyPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: [3] - org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter[ order=1000; ]
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.FilterChainProxyPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: [4] - org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter[ order=1100; ]
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.FilterChainProxyPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: [5] - org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter[ order=1200; ]
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.FilterChainProxyPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: [6] - org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter[ order=1300; ]
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.FilterChainProxyPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: [7] - org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter[ order=1400; ]
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.FilterChainProxyPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: [8] - org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter[ order=1600; ]
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.FilterChainProxyPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: [9] - org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor@aa559d
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.FilterChainProxyPostProcessor checkLoginPageIsntProtected
    INFO: Checking whether login URL '/login.htm' is accessible with your configuration
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.security.config.FilterChainProxyPostProcessor postProcessBeforeInitialization
    INFO: FilterChainProxy: FilterChainProxy[ UrlMatcher = org.springframework.security.util.AntUrlPathMatcher[requiresLowerCase='true']; Filter Chains: {/**=[org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter[ order=200; ], org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter[ order=300; ], org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter[ order=700; ], org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter[ order=1000; ], org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter[ order=1100; ], org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter[ order=1200; ], org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter[ order=1300; ], org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter[ order=1400; ], org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter[ order=1600; ], org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor@aa559d]}]
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
    INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8969 ms
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
    INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@c707c1: display name [WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet']; startup date [Sat Jul 23 04:58:06 CEST 2011]; parent: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@f8395f
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
    INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@c707c1]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@19ccb73
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
    INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@19ccb73: defining beans []; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@fd1810
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
    INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 110 ms
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
    23-jul-2011 4:58:06 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
    23-jul-2011 4:58:07 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
    23-jul-2011 4:58:07 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
    INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
    23-jul-2011 4:58:07 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
    INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
    23-jul-2011 4:58:07 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
    INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/47  config=null
    23-jul-2011 4:58:07 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 11163 ms
```

Here's the code of `spring-context.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-
    method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/Project"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.domain.Product</value>

        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
                            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Let me know if you need more code than the provided above.

Comment: I am facing same problem

Comment: The XML as posted is not [well-formed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document) - the ending tag for "beans" is missing (two instances).

Answer (score 0):

You have created the appropriate user and database ? Which would seem to be: usr = root;pwd = root; and db = Project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in method ProductDAOImpl.listProduct(), on what table does Product class map to? Make sure the table exists in the database.

Comment: Hibernate is supposed to create it, in the spring-context.xml I put this line of code <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>,  is it not supported in the latest version of mysql server?

Comment: You should take a look at the log output when the application boots up and check whether the table has been created successfully. I recommend using <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>.
See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306806/hibernate-automatically-creating-updating-the-db-tables-based-on-entity-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the application is connecting to MySQL. Because there is no port no in your configuration file. usually it runs on 3306.