# Spring hibernate/jpa automatic table generation

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

hello am duin a spring data jpa application and i want de table to generated automatically ...the test run successfully but no table is generated in database.

below are my configuration files

pesistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="purchaseHistory" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/itopupdb" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

test-db-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
">



    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="purchaseHistory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jpdDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.dreamoval.itopup.transactions.repository"/>
     <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

PurchaseHistoryTest.java

```
 package com.dreamoval.itopup.transactions.model;

import com.dreamoval.itopup.transactions.repository.PurchaseHistoryRepository;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 *
 * @author ADDICO
 */

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:META-INF/test-db-config.xml")
@Transactional
public class PurchaseHistoryTest {
     private PurchaseHistoryRepository historyRepository;

    public PurchaseHistoryTest() {
    }

     @Test
  public void GenerateDatabaseTest(){
      Assert.assertTrue(true);
  }


}
```

Comment: Have you followed this example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306806/hibernate-automatically-creating-updating-the-db-tables-based-on-entity-classes