# Can Hibernate generate tables without Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have Hibernate on my project,

but no Spring yet.

I wonder if:

Question 1:

Hibernate annotations and dialect propert in persistence.xml is enough for Hibernate to generate tables?

Question 2:
Also i guess, there must be something like Spring to look for annotations and fire a generation event and start some other things?

EDIT:

My persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Kutuphane2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <non-jta-data-source>kutuphaneDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kutuphane"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Hibernate annotations and dialect propert in persistence.xml is enough for Hibernate to generate tables?

Yes, Hibernate works by itself, Spring just helps Hibernate to provide a data source and help you to access to the Hibernate API.

> there must be something like Spring to look for annotations and fire a generation event and start some other things?

Nope, that's Hibernate work as well, just by adding `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property. This is explained here:

- [Hibernate 4.3.5 Documentation. Chapter 3. Configuration. Table 3.7. Miscellaneous Properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional-properties)
- [Hibernate: Automatically creating/updating the db tables based on entity classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/306806/1065197)
- [Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto possible values and what they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/438146/1065197)

Comment: i have Table and Entity annotations at some classes, and ´<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/> <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>´ in persistence.xml. There is no error on server start console, but no table generation action.

Comment: @merveotesi are those classes mapped in your hibernafe.cfg.xml file as well?

Comment: i think your concept of hibernate.cfg.xml is equal to my persistence.xml, and i think those both do not meet the need to generate tables "automatically", they want some boss to tell them what to do, some boss like Spring

Comment: @merveotesi if you're using JPA, then you should add the configurations on persistence.xml. If you're using Hibernate only, you should post the configurations in hibernate.cfg.xml. Anyway, in the configuration file you should map the classes and add the necessary field for table auto generation.

Comment: Thanks for patience. Do i HAVE TO map them, then why is hibernate annotations for, are they for supporting Spring when it comes, thanks very much

Comment: @merveotesi the annotations are to replace XML configuration. But you still need to add in persistence.xml or in hibernate.cfg.xml which are the mapped classes that JPA/Hibernate will use to work with. There's no tool that can auto detect your classes decorated with `@Entity` annotation and say *look, this is a class that will work with JPA*.