# Schema is not created automatically if not exist Hibernate4 and spring4 for mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Schema is not created automatically if not exist how to solve,if database name exist means tables are create automatically but schema is not exists means not created schema at run time how to do.

**hibernate properties**

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-update ** i use these keyword seperately also //create or//update**



**xml configuration**

<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.testing.domain" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

use this in your code, it drop the current schema and create a new one.

```
           <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto.create-drop}</prop>
```

Comment: then use <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto.create}</prop>

Comment: these only create sequencly at run time  new schema not for update not possible to retrieve for old record,i need one time  config to create schema if not exist and also continously to update record

Comment: check this [link]      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306806/hibernate-automatically-creating-updating-the-db-tables-based-on-entity-classes

Answer (score 0):

There is no such value as `create-update` for the property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`. All possible values are

- validate
- update
- create
- create-drop

Please read the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional). You can use `create` to create a schema, if not exists

Answer (score 0):

You can use `import.sql`.

Add a `import.sql` file in resource as follow:

```
/*create database at first time*/ 
CREATE SCHEMA your-database-name;
```

and add a line in `hibernate.cfg.xml` as follow:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
       ...
       ...
       <property name="hbm2ddl.import_files">import.sql</property>
       ...
       ...
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

So, if not exist the database, hibernate creates new db.

your `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` setting should be defining that the database is created (`options are validate, create, update or create-drop`)

There is also the undocumented value of "`none`" to disable it entirely.

defined as below

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

A value of **create** will create your tables at `sessionFactory` creation, and leave them intact.

A value of **create-drop** will create your tables, and then drop them when you close the `sessionFactory`.

**validate**: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.

**update**: update the schema.

Comment: CREATE SCHEMA your-database-name; where i have to configure

Comment: @user3928299 inside `import.sql`, this is just to create the schema if not exists, hibernate does not create scheme instance of its own, it just creates/updates tables/columns

Comment: i found solution database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hicasting?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8;
da

Answer (score 0):

One can use select value as well for hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto instead of create. We are using as below in our application and it is working fantastic. I think this is the first information on StackOverflow on select value for hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto as I googled but in vain could not find any links on select value for "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property.

```
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="databaseDataSource" />
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">select</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

In case anyone has further inputs on select option. Please share.

Comment: Looks like select option for hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is used to just query DB. This means no more DDL changes from application. Please correct if wrong.

Comment: database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hicasting?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8;