# Java/Hibernate Table does not exist error

Tags: java, hibernate

I am facing this error for quite a while now. I have managed to find a work-around by mapping the entity in my HibernateUtil class. However, I would like to achieve this using hibernate.cfg.xml.

Error that I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1441)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:491)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3201)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2411)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
at Main.main(Main.java:14)

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mydatabase.personentity' doesn't exist
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205)
... 18 more
```

Hibernate Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<!-- List of mapped classes -->
<mapping class="PersonEntity"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class PersonEntity
{
private int id;
private String name;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@Column(name = "Name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Hibernate Util:

```
public class HibernateUtil
{
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
try {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();        

    StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new 
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .configure()
            .build();

    return configuration.buildSessionFactory(standardRegistry);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
}
}

public static Session getSession()
{
return sessionFactory.openSession();
}

public static void close()
{
sessionFactory.close();
}
}
```

Main class which is meant to save some hardcoded values:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PersonEntity personEntity = new PersonEntity();

    personEntity.setId(1);
    personEntity.setName("Cris");

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();

    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(personEntity);
    session.getTransaction().commit();

}

}
```

I would be grateful if someone could help, in my opinion the problem lays in hibernate.cfg.xml, but that's just my guess.
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want hibernate to create the table if it doesnt exist? or does the table exist?

Comment: It is worth adding that when i put these lines to my hibernateUtil it works fine:
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
         configuration.configure();
         configuration.addAnnotatedClass(PersonModel.class);

Comment: Create a table if it does not exist, is it this line that is causing it?
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

Comment: @Kris22 Is this all the content in your Configuration file? `Hibernate§.cfg.xml`? It doesn't define `<class>` property to persist the `PersonEntity` class.

Comment: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306806/hibernate-automatically-creating-updating-the-db-tables-based-on-entity-classes) for creating tables with hibernate

Comment: also you have to tell hibernate that you want to persist class xyz. look [in documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html) for more information

Comment: Are you using `JPA` or "just" `Hibernate`?

Comment: just Hibernate, have a look at the config now it is complete

Comment: All clases are located in default package.

Comment: @Kris22 `<mapping class="PersonEntity"/>`  should be included with the package path : `<mapping class="package.path.PersonEntity"/>`

Comment: Which is your MySQL version?

Comment: Mysql version is 56

Comment: @Kris22,Please provide the full package structure in the mapping.

Comment: The following is my project structure:
https://postimg.org/image/4riuk2czn/

Comment: @Kris22 You should rename the default-package i.e `kriss.beans` and use it in the mapping like this: `<mapping class="kriss.beans.PersonEntity"/>` althought, the class won't be recognized and won't be persisited.

Comment: This did not help i am afraid, still same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">` to `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">` (document says so)

You should change your Sql Dialect, too. For MySQL 5.x, you should use `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect` if you are using `InnoDB` tables or `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` if you're not.

Refer to [Session Configuration document](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional).

Comment: I had to change Dialect to 
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Thank you very much and everyone else for the help.

Comment: @Kris22 you should accept the answer if it helps to solve your problem, which is very useful for later-coming users. :) Please refer this: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Done it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the table exists in the database, for example naming `person`, then you should annotate the entity with `@Table`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class PersonEntity
```

If you want `hibernate` to create the table for you, you should change `hbm2ddl.auto` to `create` at first, then change it back to **update** after the table has been created.

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

BTW, the mapping class in `hibernate.cfg.xml` should be full package name.

Comment: I have already tried changing it to create but it still says that the table does not exist.

Comment: Add `@Table(name="person")` upon the class.

Comment: Did not help as well. Thanks for helping

Comment: Then change mysql version to `5.1.38`, this configuration works fine for me, suppose it's ok too.

Comment: I know this may sound stupid, but also check if the case matches